# HTML <a> element: What is meant by the exploitation of the window.opener API?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

[Mozilla Developer Network documentation for the `target` attribute of HTML `<a>` element says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target):

> Note: When using `target`, consider adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to avoid exploitation of the `window.opener` API.

What is the meaning of phrase `exploitation of the window.opener API`?

Comment: According to the [documentation for window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) *Returns a reference to the window that opened this current window* - does that help in any way?

Comment: https://github.com/waltertamboer/window-opener-vuln

Comment: Found good explanation here: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check this link ([Refer](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)), this example has great example exploitation of the window.opener API.

This is something to do with security vulnerability. `target="_blank"` vulnerability is extremely common.

- To prevent pages from abusing window.opener, use rel=noopener.
- In order to restrict the behavior window.opener access, the original
  page needs to add a `rel="noopener"` attribute to any link that has
  `target="_blank"`. ***However, Firefox does not support that tag, so you
  should actually use `rel="noopener noreferrer"` for full coverage.***

`window.opener API` is used in the new window you just open to attack the window from where it is opened.